Nginx reverse proxy forwards axios HTTP requests to IP:Port instead of domain
I have a problem with my frontend which is built and mounted to my FastAPI application.
The frontend uses a custom axios client, which dynamically loads the baseURL from a config.js file.
No matter what I do, the frontend redirects all API calls to http://ip:port/api/path instead of https://sub.domain.tld/api/path.
Here some snippets of my custom axios client:
export const useApiStore = defineStore('api', () => {
  const baseURL = ref(window.config.baseURL || '');
  console.log('Initial baseURL:', baseURL.value);

  const client = computed(() => {
    console.log('Creating axios client with baseURL:', baseURL.value);
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: baseURL.value, 
    });
  });

  const setBaseURL = (url) => {
    console.log('Setting new baseURL:', url); 
    baseURL.value = url;
  };

  return { baseURL, client, setBaseURL };
});

Load the api.js into main.js:
const app = createApp(App);
const pinia = createPinia();
app.use(pinia);

const apiStore = useApiStore();
apiStore.setBaseURL(window.config.baseURL); 

From the vue component make an api_call:
const apiStore = useApiStore();
const response = await apiStore.client.post('/api/v1/start', payload);

This code, at least in my opinion, should work.
I've been trying to solve this bug for weeks, but just can't seem to get it fixed.
The reverse proxy cannot really be at fault here, as NginxProxyManager works with like everything, without any custom config.

Are you sure there's a value in the window.config.baseURL ? If there's no baseUrl, axios will call the origin of the current webpage.

@Nicolas Yes there was, I tested that with console.log.

The answer to my problem, was some sort of weird behaviour, axios actually made the requests to http://sub.domain.tld/api/path, while my reverse proxy forwarded that to the IP:Port, as it was http and not https. After adding a / at the end of the api_url, not the base_path, I could finally get everything to work.

You haven't provided the backend implementation in your question, but you should note that if you register /some-path/ with a slash at the end, , but access  /some-path (without the / at the end),  FastAPI/Starlette will issue a 307 redirect (appending the / at the end), so the URL matches. One could, optionally, disable the slash redirect behavior, by setting the redirect_slashes argument to False, e.g., app = FastAPI(redirect_slashes=False)
